# Can I format powershell output into collapsible Tree View in TeamCity logs?

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Is it possible to format powershell output so that it renders as a collapsible section in the TeamCity build log, Tree view?

So for example, my build step uses a powershell runner, and issues a

```
write-host " #################  deployment manifest ############################"
ls -r -i *.* | %{ $_.FullName }
```

which outputs this:

```
[15:28:13] #################  deployment manifest ############################
[15:28:13]\\10.10.10.49\d$\sites\account.foo.net\v32\Bin
[15:28:13]\\10.10.10.49\d$\sites\account.foo.net\v32\contact
[15:28:13]\\10.10.10.49\d$\sites\account.foo.net\v32\Content
[15:28:13]\\10.10.10.49\d$\sites\account.foo.net\v32\controls
[15:28:13]\\10.10.10.49\d$\sites\account.foo.net\v32\error
```

I'd like that chunk of the log to be collapsible in the Tree View.

Comment: What are the criteria that make it collapsible? I know PowerShell, but I have no idea how TeamCity works in that regard (nor do I have a clue what it even *is*).

Comment: Have you thought of creating html/html5 document with the output? You can just start write-host to a document and write in your markup, afterwards voila..

Comment: What version of TeamCity are you using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes we do this with our powershell scripts, you need to get your build script to [update Teamcity with the build status](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity). More specifically you need to [report the build progress](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildProgress) which will tell Teamcity when the start and the end of a block of work occurs. After the build has finished Teamcity will use this information to create nodes on the tree view of the log.

In powershell do the following:

```
write-host "##teamcity[progressStart '<message>']"

do work

write-host "##teamcity[progressFinish '<message>']"
```

**Note** You need to make sure that the message is the same in the start and finish message, blocks can be nested. You can also use the [block message](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-BlocksofServiceMessages) instead. I don't know exactly what the difference is but you appear to get the same results:

```
write-host "##teamcity[blockOpened name='<blockName>']"

do work

write-host "##teamcity[blockClosed name='<blockName>']"
```

Comment: Working with TC 8. Message from `progressStart` was only shown in the Overview page. Message from `blockOpened` indeed caused folding in the TreeView