# TeamCity buildlog for a single build step

Tags: powershell, build, teamcity

When teamcity executes an MSBuild step, the build log has a collapsible/expandable hierarchy. I have one big build step that runs a powershell script and the resulting build log is large and takes a lot of time to load. Is there a way to make teamcity split a single build step into it's many smaller steps instead of just one giant text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to split the build step into multiple steps in the log, but you can create nested collapsible blocks, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357717/2381).  In your script do something like:

```
write-host "##teamcity[blockOpened name='<blockName>']"
#do work
write-host "##teamcity[blockClosed name='<blockName>']"
```

Comment: Thanks tspauld! I need to pay more attention obviously.