# Forbid TeamCity reporting build step order

Tags: powershell, logging, teamcity, psake

In regard to similar topics covered by [TeamCity buildlog for a single build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587938/teamcity-buildlog-for-a-single-build-step) and [Can I format powershell output into collapsible Tree View in TeamCity logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357525/can-i-format-powershell-output-into-collapsible-tree-view-in-teamcity-logs/10357717#10357717) we have big build pipeline driven by `PSake` which have plenty set tasks. Each task is formatted by using

```
write-host "##teamcity[progressStart '<message>']"    
write-host "##teamcity[progressFinish '<message>']"
```

but while this task is still wrapped by `TeamCity` build step it puts all logs into collapsable paragraph with label `Step 1/1: Run build (Command Line) (time elaped)` and so it consequentially prefixes every following line in build log with `[Step 1/1]` which have unwanted consequences for formatting.

Is there any way to forbid `TeamCity` this kind of behavior?